# self-reference field mapping in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Lets say we have User entity class. User can be friends with other users. How can i map this self-reference collection field without creating a new entity called Connection or creating multiple entries in the database?

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
@ManyToMany
private Collection<User> friends;
...
}

USER_ID-FRIEND_ID
1 - 2
2 - 1 (duplicate... I don't need it)
```

Comment: A self-referencing many-to-many relationship is valid and can be mapped using JPA annotations.  Like all many-to-many relationships, you must define a bridge table to store both sides of the relationship.  The entity will define a field for the owning side and another field for the mapped side of the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - you need both records in the database.

Actually, for friendship relations, I'd say that a graph database like neo4j is the proper thing to use. There you have the two users and simply add an edge "friends".

Comment: interesting... i thought there could a be cheat or sth

Comment: This answer is not correct.  A self-referencing many-to-many relationship is valid and can be mapped in JPA without defining any new entities.  The relationship requires a bridge table, like all many-to-many relationships do.

Answer (score 10):

Following is snapshot from my code for ElementEntity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ElementEntity> children;

@JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", referencedColumnName = "ElementId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private ElementEntity parent;
```

Where on database there are fields:

- `ElementId` - primary key;
- `ParentId` relation with parent

Comment: thanks dude for your time. i am not looking for a parent-child relation.

Comment: @HayatiGuvence what's wrong - just rename ParentId to USER_ID and elementId to friend_Id

Answer (score 1):

At least you will need a `relational table`.

So you have a `USER` table and a `FRIENDS`:

```
user_id friend_id
   1      2
```

But @Bozho answer is way better than mine (`neo4j`).

Comment: :) you cannot have two same column name in a table

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact you can.

You can use annotations like @PreUpdate, @PrePersists, @PostUpdate and so to convert manually the elements of a collection. This way your entity can render then them way you want while in database you only store a raw text.

A more pausible alternative will be to use @Convert annotation, available since jpa 2.1 (@UserType in hibernate). It tells jpa to convert the field into another type everytime it read/save in database.
For it you should use @Convert anotation, specifying and AttributeConverter object.

For example

```
    public class Parent {
      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @Convert(converter = FriendConverter.class)
      private Set<Parent>friends;
    }
```

And converter class like the following:

```
    @Component
    public class FriendConverter implements AttributeConverter<List, String>{
      @Autowired
      private SomeRepository someRepository;

      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List attribute) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object object : attribute) {
          Parent parent = (parent) object;
          sb.append(parent.getId()).append(".");
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }

      @Override
      public List convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        String[] split = dbData.split(".");
        List<Parent>friends = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : split) {
          Parent parent = someRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(string));
          friends.add(accion);
        }
        return friends;
      }
    }
```

It is a dummy implementation but it gives you the idea.

As a personal comment, I do recommend to map the relationship as it should. In the future it will avoid you problems. AttributeConverter comes in handy when working with enums